# How can I add a column from a different table to my recursive SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

My SQL is very rusty but I need to modify a query to collect some new information. timer_call_data tcd as used in the query below also has an id field so timer_call_data.id is what I need to select. I suspect the actual solution is trivial but I'm not at all clear on where/how I can add timer_call_data to the query and join it in a way that would make it available in the final select. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
with recursive cp (id, parent, timer, name) as ( 
SELECT tc.id, tc.parent, tc.timer, timer.name 
FROM  timer_callpath tc inner join timer on tc.timer = timer.id 
where timer.trial = 2 and tc.parent is null 
UNION ALL 
SELECT d.id, d.parent, d.timer, cp.name || ' => ' || dt.name 
FROM timer_callpath AS d JOIN cp ON (d.parent = cp.id) 
join timer dt on d.timer = dt.id where dt.trial = 2 )
select cp.id from cp
left outer join timer_call_data tcd on tcd.timer_callpath = cp.id
left outer join thread h on tcd.thread = h.id
where cp.name = '.TAU application' and h.thread_index = '0'
```

Comment: Providing sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do would help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution discovered. I haven't yet puzzled out how to modify the first query to provide what I needed, but I was able to use the id it provided query to feed a second, simple query that did the trick. I'll puzzle out the approach to merging the two later but that's more for elegance than functionality. Here is the secondary query in case anyone is interested. 449 is an example value for the id provided by the first query.

```
SELECT 
  timer_call_data.id
FROM 
  public.timer_call_data, 
  public.timer_callpath, 
  public.timer, 
  public.thread
WHERE 
  timer_call_data.timer_callpath = timer_callpath.id AND
  timer_call_data.thread = thread.id AND
  timer_callpath.timer = timer.id AND
  timer.trial = 2 AND 
  timer_callpath.id = 449 AND 
  thread.thread_index = 0;
```